# How to send and receive a file from Coral dev board to a Windows laptop using the serial port OR wireless connection?

Tags: serial-port, wireless, google-coral

I have connected the Coral dev board (linux) to a Windows machine using a COM port (COM3).
In the image A it is shown my network architecture. So, there are 2 options:

- a) serial port
- b) wireless

In Image B you will see what I have tried with the COM port. 
COM3 rejected the file (I guess because it is already using COM3 with the dev board). 
COM4 worked. But I cannot find the file in Coral.

I cannot use SSH because of a problem with the public key.

Please tell me your suggestions

Thank you

Image A
[image]

Image B

[image]

EDIT

PUBLIC KEY PUSHED FROM LINUX PC TO CORAL BOARD USING MDT TOOL
[image: PUBLIC KEY PUSHED FROM LINUX PC TO CORAL BOARD USING MDT TOOL]

PUBLIC KEY GENERATED WITH PUTTYGEN AND COPIED AND PASTED TO CORAL BOARD
[image]

PUBLIC KEY GENERATED WITH PUTTYGEN AND COPIED AND PASTED TO CORAL BOARD. BUT A FORMAT HAS BEEN APPLIED
[image]
[image]

THIS IS WHAT I GET WHEN TRYING TO USE THE PUBLIC KEY FOR AUTHENTICATION
[image]

THIS THE MESSAGE THAT I GOT WHEN TRYING TO PUSH A KEY TO THE BOARD USING THE MDT TOOL (I INSTALLED LINUX ON A USB KEY)
[image]

Comment: hi, I just saw your latest edit. Where exactly are you putting your public keys?
I saw on the images that you have it on a text file? It should be in `/home/mendel/.ssh/authorized_keys` in the dev board.

Comment: Yes, it is in the dev board. I will post an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Aizzaac

I wonder what actual problem do you have with the public key?
As far as I know, you can generate a public key on putty and paste that key to `/home/mendel/authorized_keys` file in the dev board and instantly gain ssh access.
If the key pair is still an issue, you can always [enable password logins](https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-enable-ssh-password-authentication/) on the dev board.

There are also other solutions like uploading it to some server online and then download it in the dev board using wget or curl. You can also copy it to an sdcard and then access the sdcard in the board.

Edit:

Copy your files form window to a USB device (make sure it formatted to be readable from both window and linux like NTFS for instance). Plug that into dev board, find the device with

```
$ fdisk -l
```

Mount it:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/your-device /where/you/want
```

And then you can access that file there!!

Comment: I used the "enable passwords login" option. It seems it is NOT possible without MDT. I did try creating the Public key and pasting it into: ```/home/mendel/.ssh/authorized_keys```, but it did not work.

Comment: that's weird, because both methods works for me million times over LOL matter fact, it's standard linux ssh rules.
But my apologies, I don't know enough about window to really tell you much on how keys are being used on it, unfortunately :/

Comment: yes, that is weird. I think it is related to the MDT tool. I also tested adding "mdt" at the end of my public keys generated with PuTTYgen. But anyways, thank you. I learnt a lot :)